# IOException in spring-hbase application

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

While running spring-hbase application I'm getting:

> .IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={VelocityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class App {
       public static void main(final String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

            Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
            configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hortonworks.hbase.vm");
            configuration.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
            configuration.set(" fs.defaultFS","hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020");
        }
}

java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:356)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:371)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:364)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getBoolean(Configuration.java:1437)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:67)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:81)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:96)
 at org.resilinc.app.App.main(App.java:25)
```

I'm running this from eclipse which is running on Windows and I need connect to hortonworks running on vbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Windows machine, download winutil.exe from the Internet and copy into folder:

```
hadoop.home.dir = "copied folder of winutils"
```

Comment: This worked but you have to configure HADOOP_HOME=some folder
In this folder create bin and copy the win.exe in bin folder